# PostGis ST_ConcaveHull Zero Longitude Error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

**EDIT** this has now been moved to the gis-specific site [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252918/postgis-st-concavehull-zero-longitude-error)

Running the following query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-0.211393 51.606972, -0.237981 51.624109, -0.237982 51.624104)',4326),0.99))
```

returns a soft error:

```
POLYGON((-0 0,-0 0,-0 0,-0 0))
```

However if my longitudinal coordinates are bumped up (or down) out of the -0.999..0.999 range then it works:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-1.211393 51.606972, -1.237981 51.624109, -1.237982 51.624104)',4326),0.99))
```

gives

```
POLYGON((-1.211393 51.606972,-1.237982 51.624104,-1.237981 51.624109,-1.211393 51.606972))
```

What is going on here?!

Comment: I think this question may be better answered in GIS site: https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Gabriel - have now moved this question over - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252918/postgis-st-concavehull-zero-longitude-error